# Touchpad Scrolling not smooth in My Mozilla and Foxit Reader

Tags: firefox, touchpad, scrolling

I use Asus Laptop with installed touchpad driver. I have any problems about my touchpad scrolling. While i'm browsing in Mozilla Firefox and opening pdf files in FOxit Reader, my touchpad is not scrolling smoothly. But, my Chrome doesn't get the problem, so i always choose Chrome while i'm browsing without a mouse.

Especially for Mozilla Firefox, I had enabled the kinetic/smooth scrolling option in configuration panel. But, it didn't solve my problem. Does anyone know how to make my Mozilla and Foxit Reader can scrolling smoothly?

Comment: Have you tried updating your Firefox? They have added important v-sync changes to the windows version of firefox which helped me with a smoother scrolling experience. [Download it here](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/?scene=2#download-fx) and read the  [changelog for version 40](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/40.0/releasenotes/)

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I have tried and installed the newer version of Firefox. But, my problem is still occured.